# I want to fix the scroll to the body with webview

Tags: jquery

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid black; touch-action: none;" id="sign"></canvas>
```

```js
$("#sign").on('mousedown', function() {
  $("html").on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  });
});

$("#sign").on('mouseup', function(event) {
  setTimeout(scroll_off, 500);
});

function scroll_off() {
  $("html").off('scroll touchmove mousewheel');
}
```

pc is worked! but, mobile browser and webview is not working.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is usually to lock the document by setting the body's `height` to `100vh`, `width` to `100vw`, and `overflow` to `hidden`. That will prevent scrolling because there is no additional content to be scrolled. Make a CSS class that specifies this, and then add/toggle it on the `<body>` tag when needed.